# Kobold2d: KKInput anyTouchEndedThisFrame

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, kobold2d

The `anyTouchEndedThisFrame` must be buggy I´ve tried about everything now, and it will only reckonize a touch that´s ended if I move the finger, if I touch and let go at the same spot it does not reckonize it, If I am wrong please correct me

```
-(void) moveObjectToNewPosition:(KKInput *)input
{
    if (input.anyTouchEndedThisFrame) {
        [self touchesEnded:[input locationOfAnyTouchInPhase:KKTouchPhaseAny]];

    } if (input.anyTouchBeganThisFrame) {
        [self touchesBegan:[input locationOfAnyTouchInPhase:KKTouchPhaseBegan]];
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it has never worked even to me, you should implement this method which is very simple to use

```
-(void) ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches];
    UITouch * touch = [[allTouches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];

    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
    location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];

}

-(void) ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

}

-(void) ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

}
```

and add into your init this:

```
[self setTouchEnabled:YES];
```

Comment: hmm.. It seems to be the same problem using the cocos2d input as well

Comment: Working now, I had not disabled the KKInput