# Kobold2D KKInput phase KKTouchPhaseMoved is never valid?

Tags: ios, kobold2d

I am trying to get my head around the touch handling in Kobold2Ds's KKInput class.  At the moment I just have some dummy methods that are checking for the three main phases of touch input, began, moving, and ended.

However the code for touches moving never seems to get called.

Here is my code.  It is inside a CCNode subclass, that has a CCSprite that it is responsible for rendering and managing.

```
-(void) update:(ccTime)delta
{
//    NSLog(@"Update");
    KKInput* input = [KKInput sharedInput];
    if ([input isAnyTouchOnNode:tileSprite touchPhase:KKTouchPhaseMoved])
    {
        NSLog(@"Tile touched moved");
    }
    if ([input isAnyTouchOnNode:tileSprite touchPhase:KKTouchPhaseBegan])
    {
        NSLog(@"Tile touched began");
        self.frameNumber = @2;
    }
    if ([input isAnyTouchOnNode:tileSprite touchPhase:KKTouchPhaseEnded])
    {
        NSLog(@"Tile touched ended");
        self.frameNumber = @1;
    }
}
```

The code for KKTouchPhaseBegan and KKTouchPhaseEnded both get called, but the code for KKTouchPhaseMoved never does.

Can anyone clue me in to what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16519219/kobold2d-kkinput-anytouchendedthisframe

Comment: Hi Filoo so you are basically saying throw KKInput out and use the base Cocos2D handling?

Comment: it seems that I'm boycotting KKinput, I count kobold2d great for the implementation of lua and arc, but I have found some difficulty substantially in the touches, I've used some other gesture and they worked well, but for touches I prefer the methods provided by cocos. Obviously I havnt done more additional tests to find the exact way to make it work, but who has time? ^^